# Flash on google-chrome not working, but IS working in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, pulseaudio, flash

So I have the opposite problem as most posts that I've seen:  flash works in Firefox, but not in google-chrome.

The weird part is that under chrome://plugins, I can see Adobe Flash Player (v. 23.0.0.185) and that it is enabled.  I even checked the box "Always Allowed to Run."  But it doesn't work.

I've tried reinstalling google-chrome and removing my entire google-chrome profile, but it has no effect.

I don't really use flash or google-chrome, *except* for Pandora and chromecast (because I can't figure out why I have a long delay using Pithos and pulseaudio-dlna).  Pandora has not moved to HTML5 for some inane reason.

Comment: This will not fix your google chrome problem but the pithos and pianobar are packages in the repositories just for playing pandora. pianobar is command line based. It seems you are trying to get away from flash entirely but this is the only reason for chrome this is half of a way to avoid your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ianorlin.  I have Pithos and it was my go to player.  In fact, the reason for the move to Chrome is due to delays in casting from my computer to the chromecast while using Pithos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what fixed it.  But removing and reinstalling a few times seems to have done it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of `google-chrome-stable`, I think you can make Flash work by simply closing and restarting Chrome a couple of times. Finally it should enable version `24.0.0.186`. You can check the version at [this page](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).